# Saving data persistently

Tags: java, android

I have a notes app that whereby i implemented two types of views: List and Grid Views.
A user can switch between `listView` and `gridView` depending on his choice. The issue i have is that i have been trying to save the state of the view persistently such that the selected view is opened up at start up. Am trying to use `SharedPreferences` to achieve this. what am doing getting wrong in my code?

```
private static final String KEY_NAME = "viewState";
private ListView mListNotes;
    private GridView mGridNotes;
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private boolean mViewIsChanged = false;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// set the layouts for list/grid
            mListNotes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
            mGridNotes = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.main_gridview);
 // Retrieve value from Shared Preferences.
    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mViewIsChanged = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_NAME, false);
    if (!mViewIsChanged){
        mListNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
    else {
        mListNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View customTitleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu, null);
        LinearLayout mListViewSelect = (LinearLayout) customTitleView.findViewById(R.id.list_select);
        LinearLayout mGridViewSelect = (LinearLayout) customTitleView.findViewById(R.id.grid_select);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addItem:
              //  start NoteActivity
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.changeView:
                final AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                alertbox.setView(customTitleView);
                alertbox.show();
                mListViewSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


// Saving Data
sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(KEY_NAME, mViewIsChanged);
                    editor.apply();
                    mListNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        alertbox.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        mGridViewSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
// saving Data in SharedPreferences
        mViewIsChanged = true;
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_NAME, mViewIsChanged);
        editor.apply();
        mListNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        alertbox.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are retrieving the values from shared preference rightly but where are you using that value to check and load the views?  I do not see any implementation of that in your code.

Comment: i am doing that in my onOptionsItemSelected. check my updated code. or am i doing it wrongly

Comment: You are saving and retreiving data. That you are doing it correctly. But based on the retrieved data you need to add the condition in onCreate method. If shared preference is false then load the list view and if true load the grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this in your onCreate ()

```
mViewIsChanged = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_NAME, false);

mListNotes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
mGridNotes = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.main_gridview);
```

Add this

```
If (!mViewIsChanged){
  mListNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
else {
mListNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mGridNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Or put the logic provided by me after setting the adapter in your onResume() 
Hope that helps.

Comment: placing this logic in onCreate gave me a null pointer. could it be because am setting adapter in onResume?

Comment: Show you log cats. Or on which line you are getting null pointer exception?

Comment: i tried retrieving data from onResume but it did not work

Comment: Or you can put the logic provided by me in onResume after setting the adapter.

Comment: ok. am getting the null pointer because i initialized the views after setting the Boolean logic. I fixed that.

Comment: so i moved my code back to onCreate but still gives me same result. data is  not saved persistently.

Comment: Log the value of returned by shared preference while after saving and retreiving and check whether the values are correct or not

Comment: i reviewed my code as you said and i discovered that i didn't save data persistently in my listView.setOnClickListener logic.

Comment: Good to know. Gud luck. Mark the answer as accepted and upvote it. Thanks